# How to obtain a Datatable is sorted or not in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sorting, datagridview, datatables

I am working with a Datagridview in C# Winforms Application which is modified every time User saves something from a dialog/form.

As the number of rows in this datagridview is large, adding or deleting takes a huge time and as datagridview is a part of UI it can be modified only in Mainform which makes UI irresponsive.

So I am now using a method where I pass a Datatable to set as datasource of grid.

Problem is :

1. Whenever User selects something, his information is stored in hashtable
2. I convert this hashtable to a datatable - necessary info which should be displayed in datagridview (There are 5 hashtables whose info is to be displayed in single datagridview)
3. I pass this datatable to a method where it is set as datasource of datagridview
4. There is no way to know this datatable was previously sort or not
5. Also there is no way to display latest updated info to be displayed at the end/start of datagridview

Here is some code

```
private void FillDataGrid(Hashtable ht, bool isToModify)
    {
        if (ht != null && ht.Count > 0)
        {
            // Obtain a blank datatable with format of datagridview
            DataTable tableToPass = GetFormatDataTable();
            foreach (string key in ht.Keys)
            {
                List<myClass> values = ht[key] as List<myClass>;
                if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (myClass myValue in values)
                    {
                        string Id = myValue.Id;
                        Desc desc = Enumerations.Descriptions[Convert.ToInt32(Id)] as Desc;
                        if (desc != null)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = tableToPass.NewRow();
                            dr[0] = key;
                            dr[1] = desc.Name;
                            dr[2] = myValue.Timeframes;
                            tableToPass.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            SetTable(tableToPass, isToModify);
     }
}


private void SetTable(DataTable table, bool isToModify)
    {
        try
        {
            if (isToModify)
            {
                // Hence we have to append records to existing rows
                DataTable existingTable = datagridview.DataSource as DataTable;

                if (existingTable != null)
                {
                    table.Merge(existingTable);
                    datagridview..DataSource = table;
                }
                else
                    datagridview..DataSource = table;
            }
            else
            {
                datagridview..DataSource = table;
            }

            datagridview.RowTemplate.Height = 23;
            datagridview.ClearSelection();
            datagridview.Columns[1].SortMode = datagridview.Columns[2].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You [X problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) is slow update of `DataGridView` (which can be solved by virtualization afaik). You solved it with passing `DataTable`, which may be ok, all you need is to pass also information about sorting back and forth (together with `DataTable` as a separate variable). Or, well, another option is disabling column sorting at all.

Comment: Disabling Column Sorting is not an option..My Application has to work according to User requirement.. Also my only problem is not sorting, it is updating Datagridview using datatable in a correct sequence which is not happening as I am converting Hashtable(which has a random sequence) to Dattable and passing it as a source to datagridview